# How to use domain for one2many field in a tree tag inside form in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

In my odoo app I have a 'plantation' model with a one2many field "crop_ids".
I have created a form view, and inside that form view I am showing the crop_ids as a tree. What I want to do is to show only the crops with an specific condition. I try to use a domain in the view with  domain="[('is_verified', '=', True)]", but this is not working. It is showing all crops.
It is important tho appy the domain in the view and not in the model, cause I have other form view that needs to show all crops inside.
This is my code and is not working.

```
<page name="crop" string="Crop list">
    <field name="crop_ids" domain="[('is_verified', '=', True)]">
        <tree create="0" delete="0">
            <field name="name_seq"/>
            <field name="rubro"/>
            <field name="fecha"/>
            <field name="cantidad_plantas"/>
            <field name="cantidad_atrofiadas"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it seems domain element can have only 2 cases. One quick solution would be having 2 fields (crop_ids, crop_verified_ids) one with

```
domain="[('is_verified', '=', True)]"
```

other with either false or no domain. You can make each visible easily in a form view based on the condition you want.

Answer (score 0):

Odoo will use the field domain when it tries to [retrieve](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/fields.py#L2514) the lines in the comodel.

You can't apply the domain from the view

Comment: The matter is that i should get the list with that domain only for that specific form view. In other form view I have to see the list without the domain

Comment: You can't use the `domain` in the field tag